# Display FPDF report in a div from a jquery-fancybox

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, fancybox, fpdf

I have a FPDF Report generator which available for pdf download a report generated dynamically. Now I am trying to display the report on the screen through a jquery-fancybox, but the problem is that instead of being displayed to the report, is showing special characters such as:

"��W�b 2��(ʷ���:��uc��\".

I really need of the help of you.

Below the functions which generating and display fancybox and pdf.

Show fancybox and ajax-request for call the function which generating PDF:

```
$(function() {

$("*").on("click", ".fancypdf", function() {

    var data = $("form").serialize();
    var url = this.value;

    $.fancybox.open({
        type: "ajax",
        ajax: {
            dataType:"html",
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: data
        },
        href: url,
        beforeClose: function(){
            $(".fancybox-inner").unwrap();
        }

    });

    return false;
}); //click
```

});

Run the FPDF Report:

```
function exibirRelatorioPDF($dados = '') {
    $dados = $this->pesquisar();
    $ci = &get_instance();
    $ci->load->view('almembal/ajuste', $dados);
}
```

Comment: If your content is the `<embed>` tag then try using `type` to `html` (you can load the file via ajax but within fancybox display it as html). If the report won't be shown elsewhere but fancybox, I would save it to a file and display it as  `type: "iframe"`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any idea for send POST for a function (url) via jquery-fancybox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858472/any-idea-for-send-post-for-a-function-url-via-jquery-fancybox)

Comment: If you already opened a similar question, posting it many times doesn't mean you will get help faster.

Comment: No,this topic is not duplicated. If you have not noticed, the last topic was referring to sending the $ _POST. In this you can now see that I have already solved the previous problem, except that I could not post the solution because my reputation does not allow. So, how I solved the problem earlier and appeared a new I also could not solve so far, I decided to open the topic. I think it's slutty decrease my reputation because you could not distinguish the two topics.

Comment: Now I could post the solution on the other thread, you can see there, and find that they are completely different, because the former is sending the POST to fancybox and the second is related to open PDF generated by FPDF inside fancybox.